# Pass a variable from 1 event handler to another

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $type
    $('button').click(function(){

    if($(this).text() == "Click Me") {
    var $type = "passme";
    }
});

$('button[type=submit]').click(function(){
alert($type);
});





});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to somehow get this $type variable over to the other selector, I have been at this for hours and have no idea how to do it?

If I put them in the same selector (Like a selector in a selector) it alerts multiple times and really gets messed up.

Comment: Why don't you alert "passme" from the first handler itself?

Comment: @31piy What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what your goal is but I would you're always better off dealing with a form's submit event instead of it's submit button's click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works for me like this, seens you use "var" inside  a function it thinks you meant to assign the value "passme" to a local var of the function and not the var of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $type;   
    $('button').click(function(){

        if ($(this).text() == "Click Me") {
   $type = "passme";
    }
});

$('button[type=submit]').click(function(){
alert($type);
});





});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</body>
<
```

Comment: Yep, you got it... PERFECT

Comment: It was because I was declaring the var type everywhere when this was not needed and was stopping it working

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare your your variable at the top of the script 
var $type;
Above ready function and assign it like
$type = “passme”
Instead of
var $type = “passme”

Comment: Urrrrr... It has to be in the selector

Comment: That is my question dude

Comment: My answer was exactly same as the accepted answer. But I think you did not want hint, instead wanted the whole code :)